# Is there a circle class in Java like the Rectangle class

Tags: java, geometry, rectangles

Hey I was writing a quick program and something came across where I need to use a circle for collision detection. But as far as I know, there is only the Rectangle class that has the .intersects(Point p) method. Is there anything like a circle that I could use the same way?

Comment: You can use [Eclipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html), which has `contains(x, y)`.

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking the other day that Oracle had done us all a disservice by not including a dodecahedron class in the standard libraries :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a class called [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) in the `java.awt.geom` package that you can use, since it has some methods that appears to be what you're looking for. An ellipse with a width equal to its height is a circle.

One of the overloads for `contains` allows you to test for circle-point collisions:

> ```
> boolean contains(double x, double y)
> ```
>
> Tests if the specified coordinates are inside the boundary of the
>   `Shape`, as described by the definition of insideness.

Another function called `intersects` allows you to test for circle-rectangle collisions:

> ```
> boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h)
> ```
>
> Tests if the interior of the `Shape` intersects the interior of a specified rectangular area.

Note that `Ellipse2D` is an abstract class; you would use one of its nested subclasses `Ellipse2D.Double` or `Ellipse2D.Float`, the only difference being the data type used to store the dimensions.

Comment: +1, but the more appropriate method for point intersection is `contains(double x, double y)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ellipse2D, this is in the same way that a square is a rectangle a circle is an ellipse.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html

Comment: Redirect your link to the Java 7 API add I'll up vote you (Java 1.4 is nearly 10 years old :P)

Answer (score 1):

[java.awt.Shape too.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#intersects%28java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) and all the class which implements it: Arc2D, Arc2D.Double, Arc2D.Float, Area, BasicTextUI.BasicCaret, CubicCurve2D, CubicCurve2D.Double, CubicCurve2D.Float, DefaultCaret, [Ellipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html), Ellipse2D.Double, Ellipse2D.Float, GeneralPath, Line2D, Line2D.Double, Line2D.Float, Path2D, Path2D.Double, Path2D.Float, Polygon, QuadCurve2D, QuadCurve2D.Double, QuadCurve2D.Float, Rectangle, Rectangle2D, Rectangle2D.Double, Rectangle2D.Float, RectangularShape, RoundRectangle2D, RoundRectangle2D.Double, RoundRectangle2D.Float