# How can I declare a circle as a variable?

Tags: java, variables, graphics, geometry

So I'm trying to make a class where I run the java applet and then a garage band like drumset pops up where I can then click the different drums in order to make different sounds. I have the drums set to different circles that I created and I am trying to declare the circle as a variable where I can then compare the mouse click to see if the click was inside of a "Drum circle". The problem is that I get a cannot find symbol error when I try to declare the circles to variables. It works when I set the variables to rectangles, but I don't need rectangles. How can I do this?

```
public class FinalProjectst extends Applet
{
    Image picture;
    Shape base, bT, snare, lT, rT, hh, lC, rC;

    public void init()
    {
        picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"drumSet.jpg");

        base  = new Oval (355, 415, 305, 240); //Bass
        bT    = new Oval (715, 360, 325, 245); //Bottom Tom
        snare = new Oval ( 35, 410, 290, 200); //Snare
        lT    = new Oval (283, 130, 185, 165); //Left Tom
        rT    = new Oval (543, 120, 200, 175); //Right Tom
        hh    = new Oval (  0, 225, 250, 150); //High Hat
        lC    = new Oval ( 10,   0, 305, 195); //Left Cymbal
        rC    = new Oval (765,   0, 505, 275); //Right Cymbal
    }
```

If I declare shape and oval as rectangles it works but that's not what I need.

Comment: Please copy paste actual error message into question

Comment: Can you edit your sample code to show the non-working code? "This works but something else doesn't" isn't super helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a circle class in Java like the Rectangle class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674407/is-there-a-circle-class-in-java-like-the-rectangle-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class [Ellipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) that you can use. An ellipse with a width equal to its height is a circle. However it is an abstract class, so you cannot instantiate it directly. You would have to do something like:

```
Image picture;
Ellipse2D base, bT, snare, lT, rT, hh, lC, rC;

public void init()
{
    picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"drumSet.jpg");

    base  = new Ellipse2D.Double(355, 415, 305, 240); //Bass
    bT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (715, 360, 325, 245); //Bottom Tom
    snare = new Ellipse2D.Double ( 35, 410, 290, 200); //Snare
    lT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (283, 130, 185, 165); //Left Tom
    rT    = new Ellipse2D.Double (543, 120, 200, 175); //Right Tom
    hh    = new Ellipse2D.Double (  0, 225, 250, 150); //High Hat
    lC    = new Ellipse2D.Double ( 10,   0, 305, 195); //Left Cymbal
    rC    = new Ellipse2D.Double (765,   0, 505, 275); //Right Cymbal
}
```

You can also test for collisions using the method

```
boolean contains(double x, double y)
```